# Observable Nav params in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

In Angular route params is observable object. I can subscribe on this object:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(newValue => ...)
```

Can I do something similar with Ionic navParams?

```
constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.videoId = navParams.get('videoId');
}
```

Is it possible to transform videoId to observable value?

For example I have a [product page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCWDFXI). This product has many color variations. The color is a parameter from Nav params. User could change color but there is no need to do NavCtrl.push() because the color change is too small changes. It is not another one page in history. I just want to change this.color in component. But I need to subscribe on color changes in the component.

Comment: `Observable.of(navParams.get('videoId'))`? Why do you want this, what's the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to correctly navigate from product page to another product page. If I do it using NavCtrl.push() then the page is added to history, I think it will be better if new product will just replace old product.

Comment: Why would that be better? Then the user can't go back to the previous one. Please [edit] to explain the context.

Comment: ok, I updated the question

Comment: You could just set up your own Subject, then push whatever values you want into it (starting with the nav params value in the constructor). I wrote a blog post on how we've been using subjects: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to inform the color change from your page to the component, you could make use of events here. Import the events class from ionic-angular and inject it to the constructor. In your page on the button click publish an event and in the component's constructor subscribe to that event. So the code will look like as shown below.

> In your page

```
import {Events} from ‘ionic-angular‘;
onClick(){
    this.events.publish(‘myEvent‘);
}
```

> And in you component you can subscribe to that event

```
this.events.subscribe(‘myEvent’,() => {

// do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for events.
If you pass NavParams as an object, e.g. 
`{color : "red", videoId :1 }`

It is passed by reference. So any changes you make on one side will be reflected in the another, e.g. 
`{color : "blue" , videoId :1 }`.
I don't believe this re-renders the whole page.